# Spring WebFlux application ignores active profiles and application.yml when runs as bootJar

Tags: java, spring, graphql

I'm trying to create a graphql server based on spring framework with kotlin.
The problem I have faced is that my app fails when I try to start it from jar. It says graphql.packages property is not defined, so it couldnt autoconfigure the schema.
Also it says

> No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

The graphql.packages property is defined in my application.yml as follows:

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: "default"
graphql:
  packages:
    - "io.ekkles"
  subscriptions:
    # Send a ka message every 1000 ms (1 second)
    keepAliveInterval: 1000
```

However it looks like application.yml is ignored at all.
When the project runs from IntelliJ IDEA it works like a charm. The schema is configured.
Also I am able to set active profiles from IDE interface and it is also configured.

The main question is: How to make spring app read active profiles and configuration files.

My example app is here - https://github.com/ideogram-software/graphql-tests